# How to use slot in Vue 2 render function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-render-function

I'd like to do the following, but with Vue 2's render function

```html
<template>
  <imported-component>
    <template v-slot:default="{ importedFunction }">
       <button @click="importedFunction">Do something</button>
    </template>
  </import-component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `scopedSlots` for the slot
- Use the slot name ("default") plus function argument for the slot props
- Use `on` for the event handler

```js
render(h) {
  return h('imported-component', {
    scopedSlots: {
      default(slotProps) {
        return h('button', {
          on: {
            click: slotProps.importedFunction
          }
        }, 'Do something')
      }
    }
  });
}
```